# Firebase database/ Unity - dynamically creating a List of tuples

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

At the moment I am trying to write the values of my two sensors into a list of tuples (not sure if this is the best choice).

Here is all my code, followed by my intention and my goal.

```
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor;


public class FirebaseHandler: MonoBehaviour {

    public Text testTest;
    public int amountValues;
    public int historyData;

    void Start() {

        InitializeFirebase();
        createTuple ();

    }

    public void InitializeFirebase() {

        FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
        app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl("https://myfirebasedatabase.firebaseio.com/");
        if (app.Options.DatabaseUrl != null) app.SetEditorDatabaseUrl(app.Options.DatabaseUrl);

    } 

    public void createTuple() {

            FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
            .GetReference("Fridge").OrderByKey ().LimitToLast (historyData)
            .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
                if (task.IsFaulted) {
                    // Errorhandler
                }
                else if (task.IsCompleted) {


                    DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
                    // Task if completed

                    List<Tuple<string, string>> list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
                    foreach (var childSnapshot in snapshot.Children) {

                        var humidval = childSnapshot.Child ("Humidity").Value.ToString ();
                        var lightval = childSnapshot.Child ("Light").Value.ToString ();

                        list.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(humidval, lightval));

                        Debug.Log("Humidity: " + humidval + "   //   Light: " + lightval);

                    }
                    foreach (var element in list)
                    {
                        Debug.Log (element);
                    }
                }
            });                     
    }
}
```

My plan is to load the history data, set by the user, on first start. From that moment on the new values (every 5 seconds), will be written in the list and the oldest tuple removed. Therefore, e.g. if the user selects "last 10 values", the recent 10 sensor values shall be displayed. I am trying to avoid reading all "10" values (later more) by using `LimitToLast` whenever a new value is added. Later it will be upscaled up to 5 types of values and a few hundred datasets (tuples).

Right now I am struggling with creating the list of tuples. The first Debug log

```
Debug.Log("Humidity: " + humidval + "   //   Light: " + lightval);
```

displays the values correctly:

```
Humidity: 30.15   //   Light: 265
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Humidity: 30.84   //   Light: 677
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

But the second

```
Debug.Log (element);
```

only gives out the following (by using two historic datas):

```
System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String]
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

System.Tuple`2[System.String,System.String]
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

I expected an output like: 
"30.15 265
30.84 677"

Why is it not working?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug.log each element of the tuple, like

```
Debug.Log(element.Item1+": "+element.Item2);
```

Comment: Thank you! sometimes the solutions are quite easy :)